# Get a pipeline bytecode size

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have a lot of complex pipelines using 'mixed' syntax. We distribute them as a shared library based on open-source MPL project.

I called this 'mixed' syntax because we have some logic prior declarative

```
MPLpipeline{
   node('blablah'){
    do_some_init_()
   }
   pipeline{...}
}
```

We getting "method too long" error in case we add a lot of code into declerative section. It's a known Java limit of 65kb per method and seems everything inside pipeline{} is considered to be one method)

I want to run some test/script which will go through all pipelines we have and compile them including all needed  shared libraries (basicall this shared library also uses another one) and measure the size of bytecode.

Basically I need some logic which will detect if pipelines is at over limit size or not before we merge it to master branch.

Does anyone know the good way to do this? If it's even possible?

Comment: Did you get any solution over this?

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can tell its imposible to to in easy way. but you can create pipeline like so

```
// workaround to check method too large error in pipelines
void isPipelineCompiles(def body) {
  Boolean foundCompileError = false
  try {
    try {
      try {
        // 5 seconds should be enough to detect compile error
        timeout(time: 5, unit: "SECONDS") {
          body()
        }
      } catch (hudson.AbortException e) {
        println("abort exeption - all good, pipeline compiles")
      }
    } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException e) {
      println("Compile error found")
      foundCompileError = true
      throw e
    }

  } catch (ex) {
    println("global exception ${ex}")
    // we intested only in compile errors for now
    if (foundCompileError) {
      throw ex
    }
  }
}

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage("init-library") {
      steps {
        script {
          def branch
          if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /^MR-[0-9]+.*/ ) {
            branch = env.CHANGE_BRANCH
          } else {
            branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
          }
          // init library
          library "your-library-name@${branch}"
        }
      }
    }
    stage("testing-compile") {
      parallel {
        stage("check pipeline one") {
          steps {
            script {
              isPipelineCompiles() {
                // pipeline from your-library-name library, vars folder
                PipelineOne{}
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage("check pipeline two") {
          steps {
            script {
              isPipelineCompiles() {
                // pipeline from your-library-name library, vars folder
                PipelineTwo{}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`library "your-library-name@${branch}"` - branch variable can be removed, this was done for multibranch pipeline when you have feature branch and made some code and before merge to test that it works. Library loaded from jenkins global configuration

`Pipeline{}` you pipeline from vars/ folder

this pipeline should fail in case of method too large error